# Finding a length of arc, what's wrong?

Tags: definite-integrals, polar-coordinates

> Find: $$ \int \sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}dl$$
>   $$L: x^{2}+y^{2}= Rx$$

[image]

(at image $p' = -R\cdot \sin(\phi)$ )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to evaluate

$$\oint_L d\ell \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

where

$$\left ( x-\frac{R}{2}\right)^2+y^2=\frac{R^2}{4}$$

Parametrizing:

$$x(t) = \frac{R}{2} + \frac{R}{2} \cos{t} = R\cos^2{(t/2)}$$
$$y(t)=\frac{R}{2} \sin{t}$$

$$d\ell = \sqrt{x'^2+y'^2} dt = \frac{R}{2} dt$$

$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \sqrt{R x} = R |\cos{(t/2)}|$$

Then the integral is equal to

$$\frac{R}{2} R \int_0^{2 \pi} dt\, |\cos{(t/2)}| = R^2 \int_0^{\pi} dt \, \cos{(t/2)} = 2 R^2$$

Comment: OK, thanks:  I won't bother typing mine out now.  The original presentation of the question was misleading.

Comment: The OP or whoever chose the title was likely a bit confused and meant something like "find the integral over the length of arc."

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$x^2+y^2=Rx\implies \left(x-\frac R2\right)^2+y^2=\frac{R^2}4$$

If you want/can you can make a translation to get a canonical circle of radius $\,\frac R2\;$ , so its parametrization (which is where you went wrong) would be

$$x(t)=\frac R2\cos t\;,\;\;y(t)=\frac R2\sin t\;,\;\;0\le t\le 2\pi\implies$$

$$l=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}dt=\int\limits_0^{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{R^2}4\sin^2t+\frac{R^2}4\cos^2t}dt=$$

$$=\frac R2\int\limits_0^{2\pi}dt=\pi R$$

Comment: The answer is $$ 2 R^{2} $$, it's from a book of my University.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood something: are you asked to calculate the arc length of $\,x^2+y^2=Rx\,$ or to evaluate that integral that appears in your notes? Because if it the first case then you're asked to evaluate the perimeter of a circle of radius $\,R/2\,$ , which is what I wrote above and not $\,2R^2\,$ ...

Comment: I need to calculate the integral by curve. And why you didn't use the conversion to polar coordinates? It is a circle.

Comment: Then I'm afraid the question is pretty unclear: do you want to calculate the integral? Great...do they *give you* the parametrization that appears there?

Comment: "dl" is a curve $$L = x^{2}+y^{2}=Rx$$ 
We can convert x and y to polar coordinates. So x=p*sin fi, y=p*cos fi

Comment: That parametrization's wrong, @wsevendays, as Ron's answer, which seems to be on the money, shows.

Answer (score 1):

As a caution, I thought I should mention something about this curve by using this variant approach.  You can translate the equation as it stands into polar coordinates as

$$ x^2 \ + \ y^2 \ = \ Rx \ \rightarrow \ r^2 \ = \ R \cdot r \cos \theta\ \Rightarrow \ r \ = \ R \cos \theta \ . $$

The arclength integral in polar coordinates would be

$$\int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}  \sqrt{ \ r^2 \ + \ (\frac{dr}{d\theta})^2 } \ \ d\theta \ = \ \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}  \sqrt{ \ R^2 \cos^2 \theta \ + \ R^2 \sin^2 \theta } \ \ d\theta \ = \ \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2}  R\ \ d\theta \ . $$

The caution is this: while the circle which **DonAntonio** uses, which has been translated to have its center at the origin, *can* be integrated fully from $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ 2 \pi \ $ in the angle variable, the "circle" described here is in fact a "one-petal" **rosette**.  While it has the shape of a circle, it is actually traced *once completely* by taking the angle variable from $ \ 0 \ $ to $ \ \pi \ . $  Thus, the arclength integration here needs to be

$$  \int_{0}^{\pi}  R\ \ d\theta \ = \ \pi R \ , $$

which is sensible, since  $ \ R \ $ in the equation for this polar curve is actually the *diameter* of the "circle".

Comment: Yes, nice...yet the question seems to have been different. Read the comments below my answer.

Comment: So I see -- evidently, the poser of the problem wants a line integral of the function on the rosette, and not an arclength calculation. I'm looking at that now...

Comment: Yes...Ron apparently already caught the real intention. I was heavily misled by the question's title "arc lenght" and etc. Oh, well.

Comment: Thanks, I found that my θ from 0 to 2Pi was wrong.